# Http statusText not displaying in Angular error message

Tags: angular, error-handling, asp.net-core-webapi, httpresponse

I have a standard Angular front end app with a botnet core API backend. In the backend login method I have created various checks to see if a user is active, has permission to login at certain times of the day, etc. For each of these checks, I have created an error message with specific text stating why the error is being returned. For example,

// Check if user is active
if (user.IsActive == false) return BadRequest("Account not valid");

When I test from Postman it works as expected and returns the 400 Bad Request along with the message in the body of the postman response.

When calling the login method from the Angular project, the method is returning the expected response along with the response body in the network tab of the browser tools; however, the only thing I am able to get as an error in Angular is the "Bad Request". I am needing to get the actual specific error text so it can be displayed in a toaster notification to the user informing them of the specific error.

Controller

public async Task Login(LoginDto loginDto)
{
var user = await _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == loginDto.Username);

```
        // Check if user is active
        if (user.IsActive == false) return BadRequest("Account not valid");          

        // Check if user has day or time restrictions


        // Check if username is valid
        if (user == null) return Unauthorized("Invalid username");

        // Check if password is correct
        var result = await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, loginDto.Password);
        if (!result) return Unauthorized("Invalid Password");

        // Allow login
        return Ok(new
        {
            Username = user.UserName,
            IsActive = user.IsActive,
            FirstName = user.FirstName,
            LastName = user.LastName,
            Token = await _tokenService.CreateToken(user)
            
        });
    }
```

Login Component

login() {
const userlogin = this.loginForm.value;

```
this.authenticationService.login(userlogin.username, userlogin.password).subscribe(
  (response: User) =>{
    console.log(response);
    const user = response;
    if (user) {
      this.toastr.success('Login Successful');
      // localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
      localStorage.setItem('userIsActive', JSON.stringify(response.isActive));
      localStorage.setItem('userFirstName', response.firstName);
      localStorage.setItem('userLastName', response.lastName);
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } 
  }, (error) => {
    console.error(error);
    let errorMsg = error;
    console.log('Error is ' + errorMsg);

  }
);
```

Auth Service

login(username: string, password: string) {
// return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.baseUrlLogin, { username, password });
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + this.baseUrlLogin, { username, password });
}

This is what I am receiving in the console:

[Error] Bad Request
[Log] Error is Bad Request (main.js, line 121)

But in the network tab I receive what I am looking for:

Account not valid

I have tried a multitude of different variations of using HttpResponse interceptors and they all return either an undefined response or the simple Bad Request mentioned above.

Expecting
The ability to see the response body in the console so it can then be displayed in a toaster message to the user.